# Salesforce 2 Salesforce Picklist fields

Tags: formula, picklist, salesforce2salesforce

I'm unable to transfer a picklist field between 2 orgs using S2S.

I added a formula field and in the formula

```
TEXT(CustomPicklistfield__c)
```

The formula works beautifully in the source Org.

But when I 
try to map it in the S2S in the subscribe to fields area I get
the 'None available' for target fields. On hovering over the information
in the Mapping area, I see the formula text source field shows up as size 1300 Text field. I find it hard to believe formula fields don't get transferred in S2S. Since Rollup fields transfer over, I believe I'm doing something wrong.

I even created a long text field to map this, but the fields just don't open up to be mapped.

This did not help
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=business_network_tips.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: Picklist fields are designed to be directly transferrable without intermediate formula field, the subscriber org maps the publishing org's value set to its local picklist values

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the Picklist field in your Subscribed Org is a Restricted field (Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set) and that's why you are unable to see the mapping, Once you remove the Restricted checkbox you should be able to see the published picklist for field Mapping.